# Moving from digitalocean to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, digital-ocean, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I am carrying a web site from digital ocean to aws. evertyhing was good until DNS update.

I want to update 'A' record on digital ocean to point to my aws elastic load balancer.
But A record only accepts IP address and AWS elastic load balancer ip address is not static. but hostname is.

Another option is to carry nameserver from digital ocean to AWS directly but given name server update time is undeterministic i don't want this. this is a live website and during this time new data will be produced on the old web site.
Any recommendations?

Comment: You need CNAME record, not A.

Comment: @Marcin I added the cname record but it does not allow me to use bare domain name. Does that mean users should always use "www.domain.com" to visit my site? i would like www.domain.com and domain.com to both work without redirecting on server side. previously when I had an A record without www and a cname with www redirecting to without www. everything was how i wanted them.

Comment: cname can't be used for naked domains. Check DO docs. Maybe they have special record for that. In AWS it is called Alias record. Maybe DO has something similar.

Comment: they don't(although many people want this) https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-589. So I am without a solution for my case :(

Comment: Oh. So in this case you either have to move your domain to AWS or use www. If you don't mind I will provide an answer based on our discussion.

Comment: This is not a solution for me :( If I move my domain to AWS it will take time and during this time the data will continue to be generated on the old website. As I mentioned on the original question I don't want a nondeterministic switch. And I want my site to work without www also. I am sorry but your answers do not solve my problem :(

Comment: But why would your CNAME not work with EB DNS name? Its not root name.

Comment: if i use CNAME www.domain.com -> elb then people who visit www.domain.com will go to there. what about people who visit "domain.com" ? I don't want to write code on server side for this redirection. I want to basically do something like this:

A           domain.com           XXXX.elb.amazonaws.com.   ---> this I can't do because "A record" works only with IP addresses
CNAME www.domain.com  domain.come

OR:

CNAME domain.com           XXXX.elb.amazonaws.com.   ---> this I can't do because "CNAME record" does not work with bare domain names.
CNAME www.domain.com  domain.come

Comment: If DO does not support Alias records and you don't want to move, then I don't know what you can do else.

Comment: Is your EB single instance type or load balanced?

Comment: load balanced.my configuration is like that: I have a load balancer and behind it i have my dockerized django server + nginx running on ECS. I decided to take risk and move domain to AWS. "scheduled maintentance time" which I don't like :D there for accepting your answer thanks for the help.

Comment: When you provide the answer below :)

Comment: Changing nameservers should not cause any downtime when executed properly.

Comment: @dusan it is not the "downtime" i am worried if you read carefully. it is non-deterministic ie. you don't know when it will be propagated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Since DigitalOcean [does not support](https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-589) alias records, you can't use CNAME for naked domains.

But, you could get **static public IP** for your EB, if you either change your load balanced environment to single instance. Each single instance environment has static IP through elastic IP. Other way is to change your application load balancer to network load balancer, if possible. NLB has public static IPs, which you could use for the A record.